# Use of LINQ to select a subset of option chains

Tags: c#, linq

I have an option chain that I would like to subset based on the underlying price. More precisely, I want to get the puts & calls with strike prices just under, near and just above the underlying price and pair each put and call with the same strike.

Here's the bare option data in json:

```
{
"underlying_price": 130.96001,
"puts": [
    {
        "cid": "901428591898527",
        "strike": "125.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "990945460064288",
        "strike": "130.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "119741665156957",
        "strike": "135.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "712197852541730",
        "strike": "140.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "193052493845513",
        "strike": "145.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "30896117048646",
        "strike": "150.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    }
],
"calls": [
    {
        "cid": "1103304608596226",
        "strike": "125.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "28683704337826",
        "strike": "130.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "293690467884457",
        "strike": "135.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "791049407206135",
        "strike": "140.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "932015841628223",
        "strike": "145.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    },
    {
        "cid": "501320075715761",
        "strike": "150.00",
        "expiry": "Sep 18, 2015"
    }
]
```

}

This has been converted to an object of the OptionData class:

```
public class OptionData 
{
        public Option[] puts { get; set; }
        public Option[] calls { get; set; }
        public string underlying_price { get; set; }
 }

 public class Option
 {
         public string cid { get; set; }
         public string strike { get; set; }
         public string expiry { get; set; }
 }

 public class OptionPair
 {
         public decimal Strike { get; set; }
         public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
         public Option Call { get; set; }
         public Option Put { get; set; }
}
```

As in this example, the underlying price is around $130, so I would like to extract the puts & calls of strikes ($125, $130 & $135) programatically without knowing the increment ($5 in this case, it may vary in other option chains).

So I have two questions:

1. How can I do the above with LINQ or Select extension? (may consider the use of Last, First, Skip, Take, Join, etc.)
2. How Can I pair each put & call (same strike) as an object of OptionPair (prefer using LINQ syntax)?

Any idea? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's code that works for me. For the increment, I calc the difference of two strikes and added 0.99 together as a cutoff:

```
Single margin = Convert.ToSingle(puts[1].strike) - Convert.ToSingle(puts[0].strike);
        var pairs = calls.Join(puts, call => call.strike,  put => put.strike, (call, put) =>
                    new OptionPair
                    {
                        Call = call,
                        Put = put,
                        Expiry = DateTime.Parse(call.expiry),
                        Strike = Convert.ToSingle(call.strike), 
                    }).Where(pair => Math.Abs(pair.Strike - price) <= margin + 0.99);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you need?

```
decimal margin = 5.99m; // set it programatically, I made it 5.99 because of the underlying_price value in your JSON
decimal underlying_price = Decimal.Parse(data.underlying_price);
var pairs = data.puts.Join(data.calls, put => put.strike, call => call.strike, (put, call) =>
    new OptionPair
    {
        Call = call,
        Put = put,
        Expiry = DateTime.Parse(call.expiry), // or from put, this is kind of ugly - the dates theoretically can be different
        Strike = Decimal.Parse(call.strike), // or rom call
    }).Where(pair => Math.Abs(pair.Strike - underlying_price) < margin);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @gisek you saved my day. I did very minor changes as seen in the EDIT above.